# CRON job is not executing Amass exe as a subprocess?

Tags: python-3.x, cron, subdomain, ubuntu-20.04

On Ubuntu 20.04, I have setup amass.exe to detect subdomains through the CRON system, but **Amass is only working through manual execution of .py script, not through CRON.**

Installation of Amass as follows -

```
sudo apt update
Sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install amass
# amass.exe added to PROJ ROOT DIR.
```

The subdomains.py script invokes the amass exe through a subprocess call as follows:

```
import subprocess
domain = 'somedomain'
cmd = f'amass enum -passive -d {domain} -json {domain}.json'
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
# on running subprocess.. a JSON file is created which is not taking place through CRON job.
```

Rest all other cron jobs with sub-processes are working fine except for Amass, where the .exe file permissions might not be accessible to the CRON handler.

Would you please advise what issue it could be in Amass script? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Environmental Variables Missing

I don't know if the answer is still needed, but check if you've placed the proper environmental variable in the cronjob.

If not given, then just give the '**PATH**' variable and put the cronjob again.

Also, you can add the Path in the python code, in case you don't wanna give the path in cronjob by using *sys.path.insert(0,"")* (before the subprocess statement).